# Why I cannot POST to JPA created REST API endpoint?

Tags: java, rest

I started to learn Angular and with Java spring boot I provide the REST API endpoint. For that first I just wanted to check if CRUD works. For read and delete there is no problem at all but if I want to create and I have a nested element it fails. I do the testing with Postman.

I spent a week to find out how I can make it works. Tried different approaches, had long conversations with chatGPT, searched it for google, tried to find sample codes but I failed every time. Maybe it is a small stuff I overlook but I do not know what to do. And if I cannot solve this I totally stuck with the API connection between frontend and backend.

I have these dependencies in pom.xml:
spring-boot-starter-data-jpa
spring-boot-starter-data-rest
mysql-connector-j
lombok

It is very basic just for testing purpose.
Order entity:

```
import jakarta.persistence.*;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;

@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "orders")
public class Order {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    private String orderNumber;
    private String itemName;
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = false)
    private User user;
}
```

User entity:

```
import jakarta.persistence.*;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;

@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String email;
}
```

Basic JPA repository for both:

```
import com.suhitomi.angulartest.entity.Order;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.CrossOrigin;

@CrossOrigin
public interface OrderRepository extends JpaRepository<Order, Integer> {}
```

```
import com.suhitomi.angulartest.entity.User;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.CrossOrigin;

@CrossOrigin
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Integer> {
}
```

If I change the User field in the Order class to an integer the POST works without any issue but if I leave it User as it is in the code it is not able to create a new record in the database because of the non-nullability. I also removed this nullability and in that case it creates the order but the user id remains null in the database.
I use Postman for testing and here is the code:

```
{
    "orderNumber": "111333",
    "itemName": "TV",
    "user": {
        "id": 1
    }
}
```

There is no error message in the backend part (intelliJ) I only have this in Postman:

```
{
    "cause": {
        "cause": null,
        "message": "not-null property references a null or transient value : com.suhitomi.angulartest.entity.Order.user"
    },
    "message": "not-null property references a null or transient value : com.suhitomi.angulartest.entity.Order.user"
}
```

I hope I could provide anything someone can help me out.

Thank you!
p.s. I put it in [github](https://github.com/SuhiTomi/angular-test.git)

Comment: Try to give the user details without an `id`. The id is a generated value and your input `id: 1` might not work in this case.

Comment: I already tried it but I got the same message from Postman. Only provide firstName, lastName and email without the id. And the message is the same if I put valid data which is in the database or a non existing one. Also I tried different variation only add one of them or two. I also tried with ARC REST client and have the same message.